# How do you make transactional queries to NEO4J?

Tags: transactions, neo4j

```
{ 
  statements: [ 
     { statement: 'MERGE (a {nodeId: "764ed"}) ON CREATE SET a.name=\'Sample\', a:Group MERGE (b:Identity {nodeId: "89oukg"}) ON CREATE SET b.value=\'khfv9\' CREATE (b)-[:IDENTIFIES ]->(a)' },
     { statement: 'Match (i1 {value:"5678"} )-[r1]->(a), (i2 {value:"987t6b"})-[r2]->(b) CREATE (b)-[r:PART_OF]->(a) return {a: a.name, r:type(r), b:b.name}' },
     { statement: 'Match (id0:Email{value:\'x.y@hello.com\'})-[r*1..2]-(per), (group { nodeId:\'k45676\'}) Create (per)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(group)' },
     { statement: 'Match (id1:Email{value:\'y.x@hello.com\'})-[r*1..2]-(per), (group { nodeId:\'8675ef\'}) Create (per)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(group)' } 
  ] 
}
```

I basically want to

1. create a node
2. create relationship with that node to an existing node
3. match people and create relationship between people and the newly created node.

I was using

```
'http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit'
```

as the end point for me to hit. It doesn't seem to do anything for me.... No status or anything is returned

Do I have to enable something on the Neo4j server in the config to allow transactions?
What am I missing? Thank you :)

Comment: Are you POSTing, have you checked that Accept and Content-Type header are correctly defined when sending the HTTP request (see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/2.0.3/rest-api-transactional.html)?

Comment: How do you execute that JSON against neo4j?

Comment: And **please** use parameters!

Comment: @MichaelHunger Honestly, I never gotten parameters described on this page (http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-cypher.html) to work so I was just using underscore.string to parameterize. I also use 'request' node module to make the post.

Comment: Only your second statement returns something at all. And for the others I can't see how they would actually create something that would match later on and return something?

Comment: also your statements 3 and 4 are broken, you need to have a colon instead of a = inside the {prop:"value"}

Comment: I tried to recreate it, but you see quickly your statementsdo not fit togetehr http://gist.neo4j.org/?dropbox-14493611%2Fcreate_statements_so.txt

Comment: Yes I had fixed the '=' and didn't realize I posted my broken ones.. Thanks for pointing that out :) I'm not expecting anything back. I simply want to create a node and create relationships with that node with existing nodes. But I thought I'd still get some kind of status code. Also I checked my neo4j db and nothing has been created.

Comment: I just tested on my db. My queries work. Well, I'm sure there's more efficient ways to query but for what it is, it's working. I'll try to do it one by one and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Please update your question accordingly so that it shows the correct queries.

Comment: I got it working! Until now I was using a method and didn't need to specify the content-type but for transactional I had to specify the type so I just decided to use a different method. Instead of request.post(...) I'm using request(options,..) and specify the type to be json within that options. Thanks!